# Google-oauth callback works from desktop browsers but not from mobile browser

Tags: mobile, passport.js, google-oauth, redirect, passport-google-oauth

I have set up google_oauth_client and implemented google_authentication with passport.js and deployed my app to heroku. Authentication is working from desktop browsers but I am getting redirect_uri_mismatch error from browsers on mobile devices.

I have researched about this issue but there is not much on the internet. I tried to authenticate from a few desktops computers and all works. However, the same action gives the error from any mobile device.

I am not sure I need to show code here but here are snapshots of the error from my mobile and Oauth_client. Also here is the link to my app deployed in 
[heroku](https://murmuring-sea-95529.herokuapp.com/)

[mobile error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RPvC.jpg)

[google_oauth_client_setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cL9QG.png)

Answer (score 0):

For those who may encounter this issue. The fix is actually fairly simple. Mobile browsers don't understand this GoogleStrategy set up that I had below:

```
    clientID: keys.googleClientID,
    clientSecret: keys.googleClientSecret,
    callbackURL: '/auth/google/callback',
    proxy: true
```

You will have to do something like this. Make sure you config file has an absolute path for your heroku domain and than just call it as in keys.redirectURI

```
    clientID: keys.googleClientID,
    clientSecret: keys.googleClientSecret,
    callbackURL: keys.redirectURI + '/auth/google/callback',
```

I think the issue is 'proxy.true' . Perhaps Google is not proxying to the mobile browser correctly. As you will see from my screenshot above is that it is trying to redirect to http as opposed to https.